# Numpy outputting incorrect eigenvectors

Tags: python, numpy, math, eigenvector

I need to output eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix. This seems like a trivial task using a function like `numpy.linalg.eig`. It turned out that it outputs correct eigenvalues but there is something wrong with eigenvectors.

Say we have a matrix A:

[image]

We know that the eigenvalues for this are:

[image]

Similarly, the eigenvectors for this are:

[image]

[image]

So using the equation,

[image]

For the first eigenvalue, we have:

[image]

You can test it using this code:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 2],
              [2, 3]])
I = np.eye(2)

eigenvector = [[1, 2], 
               [-2, 1]]
eigenvalue = [4, -1]

for i in range(2):
    print(f"eigenvalue = {eigenvalue[i]}, eigenvector = {eigenvector[i]}")
    print(f"(A-λ*I)v = {(A-eigenvalue[i]*I)@eigenvector[i]}")
    print(" ")
```

However, if we try `numpy.linalg.eig` to compute the eigenvectors and eigenvalues we run into some issues.

This finds the following, incorrect, eigenvalues:

[image]

Similarly, the eigenvectors that it finds are:

[image]

[image]

Now when we test the first eigenvector we get results that are different than zero:

[image]

You can see this using this code:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig

A = np.array([[0, 2],
              [2, 3]])
I = np.eye(2)

eigenvalue, eigenvector = eig(A)
for i in range(2):
    print(f"eigenvalue = {eigenvalue[i]}, eigenvector = {eigenvector[i]}")
    print(f"(A-λ*I)v = {(A-eigenvalue[i]*I)@eigenvector[i]}")
    print(" ")
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the correct eigenvectors using `numpy.linalg.eig`?

Comment: are you testing columns as documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy returns the normalized eigenvectors, i.e. they have unit length (as outlined in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html)). Also, you need to select the first column to get the first eigenvector.
If you use `eigenvector[:, 0]*np.sqrt(5)`, you will see that the eigenvector is the same as the one you computed by hand.

Comment: I was aware of normalisation. This is what I was after, use the columns rather than rows, silly me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First a couple of formatting notes.

For ordinary browsers, the math notation is not particularly readable, e.g. `$\lambda_2 = 4$.`

And when running code with prints, it's nice if you actually show the results.  Thus:

```
In [72]: i = 0
    ...: print('eigenvalue = {}, eigenvector = {}'.format(eigenvalue[i],eigenvector[i]))
    ...: print('(A-λ*I)v = {}'.format(np.matmul((A-eigenvalue[i]*I),eigenvector[i])))
    ...: print(' ')
    ...: i = 1
    ...: print('eigenvalue = {}, eigenvector = {}'.format(eigenvalue[i],eigenvector[i]))
    ...: print('(A-λ*I)v = {}'.format(np.matmul((A-eigenvalue[i]*I),eigenvector[i])))
eigenvalue = -1.0, eigenvector = [-0.89442719 -0.4472136 ]
(A-λ*I)v = [-1.78885438 -3.57770876]
 

eigenvalue = 4.0, eigenvector = [ 0.4472136  -0.89442719]
(A-λ*I)v = [-3.57770876  1.78885438]
```

With numpy you can print whole arrays, such as

```
In [75]: eigenvalue
Out[75]: array([-1.,  4.])

In [76]: eigenvector
Out[76]: 
array([[-0.89442719, -0.4472136 ],
       [ 0.4472136 , -0.89442719]])
```

Compare that with your values:

```
eigenvector = [[1, 2], [-2, 1]]
eigenvalue = [4, -1]
```

`eigenvalue` order is switched; `eigenvector` values are in the same 2:1 ratio. Matching signs (by column) takes a bit more thought.

And if we use columns instead of rows,

```
In [77]: i = 0
    ...: print('(A-λ*I)v = {}'.format(np.matmul((A-eigenvalue[i]*I),eigenvector[:,i])))
    ...: print(' ')
    ...: i = 1
    ...: print('(A-λ*I)v = {}'.format(np.matmul((A-eigenvalue[i]*I),eigenvector[:,i])))
(A-λ*I)v = [0. 0.]
(A-λ*I)v = [0. 0.]
```

A quick search of `[numpy] eigenvectors` shows that SO questions mistaking rows and columns go back at least to 2015.

Comment: Thanks a lot for letting me know about the formatting. Yes, the use of rows rather than columns was the issue.